# web scraping with Beautifulsoup - output unintentionally merging words (e.g., ThisHappens)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-parsing

I am trying to web scrape some research study abstracts and some words are just being merged together. Unfortunately, it's not consistent enough where I can just do something like `outputexample.replace("WordMerge","")`.

For example, in the URL provided in my code, the first line in the output is:

```
AbstractsPublic AbstractDownload this abstract: English (pdf) | Español (pdf) | Audio Recording (mp3)
```

I would like to prevent this from happening and maintain as much of the original text and format as possible.

```
 import requests
 import time
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import re

 urlsummary ='https://www.pcori.org/research-results/2013/testing-new- 
 ways-schedule-appointments-community-health-centers-help-patients'
 html = requests.get(urlsummary).content
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

 abstract = soup.find(class_='pane pane--node').get_text()
 print(abstract)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
.get_text(" ")
```

From [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

> You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together: